# Bash output using awk or sed possibly

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting, grep

I have a file that looks like the below.

INPUT FILE SAMPLE

```
$ more showportlist
1/1
1/2
1/3
1/4
2/1
2/2
2/4
3/1
3/2
3/3
3/4
4/1
4/2
4/3
```

And I have the script below

```
#!/bin/bash

cat ports.csv | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -u > showportlist
#echo "$var2" > BNGIP
echo "proc_sendcommands()" > showportlist2
echo "{" >> showportlist2
echo 'rt_host=$1' >> showportlist2
echo 'rt_username=$USERNAME' >> showportlist2
echo 'rt_password=$PASSWORD' >> showportlist2
cat showportlist | while read LINE; do
    echo "rt_command_$((i++))='show circuit $LINE summary | grep bound'" >> showportlist2
done
```

The script outputs a file that looks like this

```
proc_sendcommands()
{
    rt_host=$1
    rt_username=$USERNAME
    rt_password=$PASSWORD
    rt_command_0='show circuit 1/1 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_1='show circuit 1/2 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_2='show circuit 1/3 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_3='show circuit 1/4 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_4='show circuit 2/1 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_5='show circuit 2/2 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_6='show circuit 2/4 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_7='show circuit 3/1 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_8='show circuit 3/2 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_9='show circuit 3/3 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_10='show circuit 3/4 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_11='show circuit 4/1 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_12='show circuit 4/2 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_13='show circuit 4/3 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_14='show circuit 4/4 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_15='show circuit 5/1 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_16='show circuit 5/2 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_17='show circuit 5/3 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_18='show circuit 5/4 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_19='show circuit 6/1 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_20='show circuit 6/2 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_21='show circuit 6/3 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_22='show circuit 6/4 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_23='show circuit 9/1 summary | grep bound'
    rt_command_24='show circuit 9/2 summary | grep bound'
```

But I also need it to output the below I am just not sure how to get there.

(sleep 1; echo $rt_username; sleep 1; echo $rt_password; sleep 1;echo $rt_command_0;sleep 1;echo $rt_command_1;sle

ep 10;echo $rt_command_2;sleep 1;echo $rt_command_3;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_4;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_5;sleep

10; echo $rt_command_6;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_7;sleep 1;echo $rt_command_8;sleep 1;echo $rt_command_9;sleep

5;echo $rt_command_10;sleep 1;echo $rt_command_11;sleep 1;echo $rt_command_12;sleep 1;echo $rt_command_13;sleep 1;

echo $rt_command_14;sleep 1;echo $rt_command_15;sleep 1;echo $rt_command_16;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_17;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_18;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_19;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_20;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_21;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_22;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_23;sleep 1; echo $rt_command_24;sleep 1; echo "exit" ) | ssh $rt_host

Comment: Thanks to anyone for any help I can get, still a little new at this.

Comment: Please, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If your input file were 2 lines instead of 14, and your sample output were similarly 1/7 of the size shown now, could you ask the same question and get an answer that would solve your problem? If so it would hugely increase the chance that people stop by your question and try to help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: Please use code tags for your question and make it clear.

Comment: what is the main goal? elaborate your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is quite trivial:

```
typeset -j i
echo -n '(sleep 1; echo $rt_username; sleep 1; echo $rt_password; sleep 1;'
j=0
while [ $j -lt $i ] ; do
    j=j+1
    echo -n "$rt_command_$j;sleep1;"
done
echo 'echo "exit" ) | ssh $rt_host'
```

but this is almost certainly not what you want to do.

If it is possible, you should set-up public/private key authentication for ssh with your `$rt_host` which will remove the requirement to login every time.

If setting up key-authentication is absolutely impossible, you will need to fall-back to `expect`.  As an example:

```
spawn ssh -l username target_host
expect "ord\\: "
send "secret_password\r"
set handle [ open file_with_commands r ]
while { ! [eof $handle] } {
    gets $handle buf
    expect "\\$"
    send "$buf\r"
}
send "exit\r"
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Ljm